# $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry of 2d Majorana fermion theory

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, chirality, majorana-fermions

I'm reading [A Web of 2d Dualities: Z2 Gauge Fields and Arf Invariants](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05550), and confused by a simple statement: the Euclidean kinetic action is invariant under a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry, while the mass term changes sign.

The action is is given by eq (2.1)),
$$
\int_X i \bar{\chi}\gamma^\mu D_\mu \chi + i m \bar \chi \gamma^3 \chi \ ,
$$
where $\gamma^1 = \sigma^1$, $\gamma^2 = \sigma^3$, $\gamma^3 = \gamma^1 \gamma^2= - i \sigma^2$, $\bar \chi = \chi^\dagger$ (in the footnote). The $\gamma^3$ is real and anti-symmetric, $(\gamma^3)^\dagger = - \gamma^3$, and $(\gamma^3)^2 = -1$.

The proposed symmetry is given by  $\chi \to i \gamma^3 \chi$, and therefore $\chi^\dagger \to (i \gamma^3 \chi)^\dagger = -i \chi^\dagger(\gamma^3)^\dagger = i \chi^\dagger \gamma^3 = i \bar \chi \gamma^3$.

We can now check the invariance of the action.

- The kinetic term

$$i \bar \chi \gamma^\mu D_\mu \chi \to i ( i \bar \chi \gamma^3) \gamma^\mu D_\mu (i \gamma^3 \chi) = - i \bar \chi \gamma^3 \gamma^\mu D_\mu \gamma^3 \chi
= + i \bar \chi  \gamma^\mu D_\mu \gamma^3 \gamma^3 \chi = - i \bar \chi \gamma^\mu D_\mu \chi \ .
$$

- The mass term

$$
i m \bar \chi \gamma^3 \chi \to i m (i \bar \chi \gamma^3) \gamma^3 (i \gamma^3\chi)
= - i m \bar \chi \gamma^3\gamma^3\gamma^3 \chi
= i m \bar \chi \gamma^3 \chi \ . 
$$

It seems the result should be **exactly opposite** to what is said in the paper: the kinetic term changes sign, and the mass term is invariant.

**I wonder what I have missed/gone wrong in the above understanding?**